# Rails 4 ActiveJobs using different enqueue adapter and having NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, nomethoderror, rails-activejob

I am trying to run an ActiveJob job from a controller method, but it fails and I can't spot the right place of the issue:

***#app/controllers/users_controller.rb***

```
1   class UsersController < ApplicationController
2       def new
3         @user = User.new
4       end1 
5   
6     def create
7       @user = User.create(user_params)
8       PoliciesChecksJob.new(@user.id).enqueue
9       # redirect to somewhere
10   end1 
11  end
```

***#app/jobs/policies_checks_job.rb***

```
class PoliciesChecksJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id)
    SearchPoliciesCommands.new.execute(user_id)
  end
end
```

**Logs summary:**

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-03-30 15:01:03 +0100 
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
...(params)
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
... (inserts the user)
(0.3ms)  COMMIT 
[ActiveJob] Enqueued PoliciesChecksJob (Job ID: da...e2) to Sneakers(default) with arguments: 1

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 76ms

NoMethodError (private method `warn' called for nil:NilClass):   
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

I'd appreciate any thought.

Comment: Which is line 9? What's the view? Looks like the job is enqueued.

Comment: Just added the lines number

Answer (score 0):

Basically there was a little problem with the **enqueue adapter**:
I prefer to use [Sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) due the fact that it does work fine with [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

1. So I had to specify that I want a different enqueue adapter than the default one:

**#config/application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sneakers
```

2. Install **RabbitMQ**, and **start** it:

   *(preferible in a different terminal tab)*

   > $ rabbitmq-server
3. Install the gem **sneakers** and **run** its deamon in *(preferible other terminal tab)*:

> $ sneakers work ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SneakersAdapter::JobWrapper
>   --require app/jobs/policies_checks_job.rb

Comment: Hi, I had an error
   `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveJob (NameError)